# form submission not working after SSL and does not submitimage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a `form` to `submit model`, it was working correctly before `ssl`
but does not work when uploading pictures after `ssl`
when we don't upload pictures it's work correctly but when we choose an image and click to submit it's not work.

`form` is here

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditAttorney", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Detaylı Açıklama(kullanıcı için)</label>
                        <div class="input-group col-md-9">
                            <textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="AttorneyDescription" id="AttorneyDescription" rows="6" data-error-container="#editor2_error">   @Html.Raw(Model.AttorneyDescription)</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                                <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                    <img src="https://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"> </div>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="btn default btn-file">
                                        <span class="fileinput-new"> Resim Seç</span>
                                        <span class="fileinput-exists"> Değiştir </span>
                                        <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="imageFile" accept="image/*">
                                    </span>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Sil </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
                            @if (ViewBag.AttorneyImage != null)
                            {
                                <a class="example-image-link" href="@Url.Content(ViewBag.AttorneyImage)" data-lightbox="example-1"><img class="example-image" src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.AttorneyImage)" alt="image-1" width="230" /></a>
                            }
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn blue">Güncelle</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ListOfAttorney","Admin")'">İptal</button>
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: What does ViewBag.AttorneyImage return?

Comment: this page is for edit if model has an image i send it with viewbag to display

Comment: murtaza safar I mean what URL is returned, can you trace it and ensure it is using https?

Comment: I can see image which is stored on the ViewBag on the page, problem is on the file input if i  don't choose the picture it's work, but when i choose an image to input file form does not submit